# Google Sheet Filter function and Concatenate in a Cell

Tags: google-sheets

To All Google Sheet Expert,

I need help to solve this problem in my google sheets.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v99mT.png)

Based on my previous search and question, I can use combination between TextJoin and Filter.

How can I achieve those expected result?

What should I fill in M4, M5, N4, N5, O4, O5?

[This is link to my sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GBmcjyr-YS_uGeNDajHGfnnnBrJS5uBUTfca531OC_o/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Im trying using =filter($A$4:$A&" "&$B$4:$B, E3:K3=M$2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One possible approach

This is for cell M3 for example:

```
=JOIN(
    CHAR(10),
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        (FILTER(E3:K3, VLOOKUP(E3:K3,$A$4:$B$10,2,FALSE) = M2))
        &" "&
        (FILTER(E4:K4, VLOOKUP(E3:K3,$A$4:$B$10,2,FALSE) = M2))
    )
)
```

Starting from the inner-most formulae

- The `VLOOKUP` is needed to match the food name to the type.
- This value is then used to `FILTER` BOTH the price and the titles of the food. You need two filters for this, one for the price and one for the title. Using onlt this it will give you:

[image]

- These two rows now need to be concatenated with the `&` symbol, wrapped in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

[image]

- Finally these rows need to be joined with `JOIN` using a newline `CHAR(10)`.

[image]

#### Reference

- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`CHAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)

Comment: It didnt't work. Message: No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

Comment: You are right, I needed to change one reference which didn't update, edited answer, try now

Comment: Thats work. I do some edit, so I can drag down and right becoming:

=JOIN(
    CHAR(10),
    ARRAYFORMULA(
        (FILTER($E$3:$K$3, VLOOKUP($E$3:$K$3,$A$4:$B$10,2,FALSE) = M$2))
        &" "&
        (FILTER($E4:$K4, VLOOKUP($E$3:$K$3,$A$4:$B$10,2,FALSE) = M$2))
    )
)

Thank you, really appreciate it!